# Mac WindowServer randomly starts hogging CPU with no explanation

Tags: macos, cpu, performance, cpu-usage

I have a 2017 Macbook running Monterrey 12.5 (cant update because it's a company laptop) connected to 4 external monitors.

Usually it runs well but randomly it will suddenly slow down to a crawl and my cursor becomes beachballs as if a background process kicked off and took all the CPU.  Running "top" shows WindowServer shot up to 50% or more CPU.

WindowServer usually consumes low CPU so I can't figure out why the WindowServer process decides to suddenly up the CPU usage when no new tabs/processes have started.  It seems to be slowed down by something else other than the number of tabs/processes.  I've already optimized the display settings for performance.   How can I find what triggers WindowServer to spike cpu usage randomly?

How can I troubleshoot further why WindowServer randomly kicks in and hogs the CPU?

Comment: I'd be inclined to leave Activity Monitor open & in view, so you can just quickly glance over if/when something goes out of kilter. Might give you a better idea of what's coinciding. 50% [of one core] shouldn't really be enough to choke the system.